# Matplotlib grouping subplots adding space between clusters

Tags: python, matplotlib, grouping, subplot

I am using the following code to make a plot composed of 16 subplots

```
# Generate figure
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12.25))

plt.subplot(4,4,1)
im = plt.imshow(qcf1r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.title(r'Quantum', loc='center', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r'$\xi_p$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=0.013' , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,2)
im = plt.imshow(ccf1r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.title(r'Classical', loc='center' , fontsize = 12)
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.013,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,3)
im = plt.imshow(qcf2r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.title(r'Quantum', loc='center' , fontsize = 12)
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.071,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,4)
im = plt.imshow(ccf2r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.title(r'Classical', loc='center' , fontsize = 12)
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.071,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,5)
im = plt.imshow(qcf1i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.ylabel(r'$\xi_p$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.013,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,6)
im = plt.imshow(ccf1i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.013,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,7)
im = plt.imshow(qcf2i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.071,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,8)
im = plt.imshow(ccf2i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.071,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,9)
im = plt.imshow(qcf3r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.ylabel(r'$\xi_p$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.157,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,10)
im = plt.imshow(ccf3r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.157,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,11)
im = plt.imshow(qcf4r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.393,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,12)
im = plt.imshow(ccf4r,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.393,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,13)
im = plt.imshow(qcf3i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.xlabel(r'$\xi_q$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\xi_p$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.157,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,14)
im = plt.imshow(ccf3i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.xlabel(r'$\xi_q$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.157,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Re\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,15)
im = plt.imshow(qcf4i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.xlabel(r'$\xi_q$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.393,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

plt.subplot(4,4,16)
im = plt.imshow(ccf4i,extent=([-x0,x0,-x0,x0]),cmap='seismic',aspect='equal',origin='lower')
plt.xlabel(r'$\xi_q$')
plt.text(-10, 9, 't=%s'%format(0.393,'.3f') , fontsize = 10)
plt.text(-10,-9, r'$\Im\left[ \chi(\xi_q,\xi_p) \right]$', fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-x0,x0)
plt.xticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(-9,9,7), fontsize=0)
plt.tick_params(width=1,length=5,direction='in',top= 'True', right = 'True')
plt.grid(color='gray', linestyle=':', linewidth=.2)
im.set_norm(cnorm)

cax1 = plt.axes([0.20,0.93,0.60,0.01]) #([0.94,0.66,0.03,0.19])
clb = plt.colorbar(cax=cax1, orientation= 'horizontal')
clb.ax.set_title(r'$\chi(\xi_q,\xi_p)$')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.00, hspace=-0.01)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

and I am getting this [image: 16 subplots all sharing axes] which is nice but not ideal

what I would like to do is group them in 4 clusters of 4 plots, separated by a small distance. like in this paint-made version [image]

I tried changing [subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) but this changes the spacing between all figures.
So far I haven't found any useful or related answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of things, I think you'll have to make creative use of [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html?highlight=gridspec#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec). See [more examples here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-gridspec-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12.25))

gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2, hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)
gsList = [gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,2, subplot_spec=gs0[i,j], hspace=0, wspace=0) for i in range(2) for j in range(2)]

plt.subplot(gsList[0][0,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[0][0,1])
plt.subplot(gsList[0][1,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[0][1,1])

plt.subplot(gsList[1][0,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[1][0,1])
plt.subplot(gsList[1][1,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[1][1,1])

plt.subplot(gsList[2][0,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[2][0,1])
plt.subplot(gsList[2][1,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[2][1,1])

plt.subplot(gsList[3][0,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[3][0,1])
plt.subplot(gsList[3][1,0])
plt.subplot(gsList[3][1,1])
```

[image]